# HTML CSS Nav get my margin-top of Table

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sidenav

I have a SideNav which is `position: absolute;` and is fill all the left side of screen and my table is on the middle of screen, but if I want to apply a `margin-top:50px;` the SideNav get it too.

If I remove the `position` it works but it can't fill all the left side anymore.

- App.css (Main CSS file) : https://hastebin.com/fodafasidi.css
- Navig.js : https://hastebin.com/uluhogetuj.xml

I don't know why it does that, thanks for help.

[image: Web page with the issue]

```css
body{
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  height: 80px;
}

.App-header {
  background-color: #222;
  height: 150px;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
}

.App-title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.App-intro {
  font-size: large;
}

table {
  text-align: center;
  width: 500px;
  margin:auto;
  margin-right: 40%;
  border-color: #0585e1;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: groove;
  padding: 20px 0;
  background-color: #c9d4e8;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

table input {
  width: 200px;
  border-color: #0585e1;
  border-style: groove;
  padding: 4px;
  font-size: 13px;
  background-color: #c9d4e8;
  color: #0585e1;
  margin:3px 0;
}

table td {
  color: #0585e1;

}

button {
  color: #0585e1;
  background-color: #c9d4e8;
  margin-top: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-color: #0585e1;
  border-style: groove;
}

#navigator {
  background: #354256;
  color: #0585e1;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of applying `margin-top: 50px;` to your `<body>` element, apply:

```
padding-top: 50px;
```

also, in addition to declaring `position: absolute` for `#navigator`, you should, ideally, provide explicit co-ordinates.

**e.g.**

```
#navigator {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  color: #0585e1;
  background-color: #354256;
}
```